How to delete a MessageCreateListener on Javacord, from within it?
I'm trying to delete a MessageCreateListener. This command is supposed to create a questionnaire, in this case, an survey. It asks for the title, then for the questions and so on. The "title" question should be answered only once, and then the listener deleted for the next question to be asked.
In this current state, the listener just works indefinitely and every single message I send on the channel gets listened and the embed gets edited to "Title defined: *message* "
I tried to change this code a whole lot of time and I did not work. How can I do it? Can be from within the listener declaration itself, or outside after it was executed ONCE.
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> survey = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

EmbedBuilder titleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("What should be the survey's title?")
    .setDescription("Type below:")
    .setColor(PURPLE);

Message titleMessage = channel.sendMessage(titleEmbed).exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class)).join();

Runnable timeoutTask = () -> {
    channel.sendMessage("Limit answer time reached. Cancelling action. ||" + author.getMentionTag() + "||").exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (survey.get("title") == null) {
        server.getTextChannels().forEach(textChannel -> {
        if (textChannel.getId() == channel.getId()) {
            textChannel.delete().exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class));
            }
        });
    }
};

ScheduledFuture<?> timeoutFuture = scheduler.schedule(timeoutTask, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

channel.addMessageCreateListener(event -> {
    if (!event.getMessageAuthor().asUser().orElse(null).equals(author)) {
        return;
    }
    timeoutFuture.cancel(false);
    
    String title = event.getMessageContent();
    titleEmbed.setDescription("Title defined: " + Markdown.bold(title) + "\nTo change the title, click on the pencil (✏️) below.");
    titleMessage.addReaction("✏️").exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class));
    titleMessage.edit(titleEmbed).exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class));
    firstMessage.delete().exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class));
    event.getMessage().delete().exceptionally(ExceptionLogger.get(MissingPermissionsException.class));
    survey.put("title", new ArrayList<String>());
    survey.get("title").add(title);
    channel.removeListener(MessageCreateListener.class, this);
});

The code above even throws an error. Line 74 is event.getMessage().delete()..., under the listener.
ERROR org.javacord.core.util.logging.ExceptionLoggerDelegateImpl - Caught unhandled exception!
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: Unknown Message
        at me.eduardogottert.commands.ComandoPesquisa.lambda$2(ComandoPesquisa.java:74) ~[classes/:?]

